# Criteria API - Hibernate vs JPA 2

Tags: java, orm, hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteria

Vou tentar frasear essa pergunta da maneira menos opinativa possível no espírito da stackoverflow em inglês. Para um novo projeto preciso tomar a decisão entre usar a API do JPA 2 ou do Hibernate (enquanto é tecnicamente possível misturar as duas, por razões arquiteturais teremos que escolher entre uma ou outra).

Tenho um time de desenvolvedores versados em hibernate que conhecem bastante de HQL e da API nativa de Criteria.

Particularmente, como alguém que leu o livro [Pro JPA 2](http://www.apress.com/9781430219569/) de ponta a ponta, penso que o JPQL é suficientemente parecido com o HQL para que a transição não seja problemática.

Já do lado da API de Criteria, que é largamente utilizada pelos desenvolvedores, a diferença é  bem mais significativa. Enquanto a API do JPA 2 me parece bem mais poderosa do que a do Hibernate ela tem uma curva de aprendizado para os desenvolvedores: metamodelo, queries fortemente tipadas, etc.

O lado positivo é que, além de tornar o projeto independente do provedor ORM, a nova API possui varias *features* úteis como suporte à clausula `having` (problema em aberto no hibernate [desde 2005](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1043) que sempre nos trouxe dores de cabeça).

Minha pergunta então é. Alguém de vocês está usando a API de Criteria do JPA 2 em projetos grandes? Alguém que tenha experiência com ambas as APIs poderia fazer um comparativo de prós e contras de cada uma?

Comment: O problema desse tipo de pergunta não é porque é opinativa, mas porque as respostas serão mais baseadas em opiniões. A pergunta fica uma espécie de enquete, que não é muito apropriada para o formato do SO.

Comment: Tendo dito isso, tem um aforismo que diz: "quando você está achando muito difícil de escolher entre duas coisas, provavelmente não é uma decisão muito importante". Acho que se aplica nesse caso: a decisão entre JPA2 e Hibernate provavelmente não vai impactar muito no sucesso/fracasso do projeto grande. =)

Comment: Eu conheço quase zero sobre o assunto em si, mas parece que a pergunta está procurando informações de forma objetiva e a primeira resposta parece ser bem elaborada. A linha é tênue mas pode dar certo. De qualquer forma, quando surge dúvidas, sempre é bom refletir se ela pode ser melhorada.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Escolher qual API utilizar não seria apenas uma escolha de mão no código, mas também deve-se pensar em arquitetura. Vou descrever o que penso sobre os dois:

### Considerações sobre arquitetura

A vantagem de usar a API de Criteria nativa do JPA é que:

1. Você terá mais flexibilidade para mudar de implementação, você poderá manter o código de JPA utilizado. Como apenas as interfaces do JPA será utilizada, tanto como Eclipse, OpenJPA, Hibernate, etc terão essas interfaces implementada.
2. Qualquer nova feature que for adicionar em uma nova versão, você já terá acesso
3. Você tem a opção de usar a criteria de modo tipado ou não, o modo tipado já mostra erro em tempo de compilação
4. Permite que consultas complexas sejam realizadas, e caso haja erro na implementação (hibernate por exemplo), basta fazer uma portabilidade de provider (ir para EclipseLink por exemplo)

A desvantagem de se usar a API nativa do JPA é:

1. Complexidade. Devido a grande quantidade de classes que existem na API nativa, conhecer todas e seus objetivos levará um bom tempo
2. Verbosidade. É uma API muito verbosa, um comando simples como select leva a várias linhas de códigos

A vantagem de usar a API de Criteria do Hibernate é que:

1. Código simples e fácil de utilizar
2. Ter acesso a funcionalidades que não estarão presentes na API nativa

A desvantagem de usar a API de Criteria do Hibernate é que:

1. Você vai estar preso a uma implementação. Caso algum problema aconteça com o Hibernate você terá problemas em migrar para outra implementação. Algum tempo atrás, por exemplo, foi lançado o Batoo que prometeu uma performance 15x mais rápida que o Hibernate. Imagine que seu projeto está tendo problemas de performance e você gostaria de testar essa nova implementação? Ao utilizar API do Hiberate esse teste demoraria muito tempo. Já com API nativa do JPA seria feita mais rapidamente.
2. Tamanho do Artefato. Infelizmente o Hibernate tem muitas dependências, com isso, o tamanho do war/ear aumenta consideravelmente. Isso poderá ser problema quando o upload do artefato para o ambiente de produção não tem um link bom de internet.

---

### Considerações sobre o Código

Veja como ficará um select * from pessoa (entity Person) ao utilizar a criteria do JPA:

```
CriteriaQuery<Person> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> root = criteriaQuery.from(Person.class);
criteriaQuery.select(root); // necessário caso uma condição where seja adicionada na consulta
TypedQuery<Person> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
query.getResultList();
```

Diversas linhas de código para realizar uma consulta simples. Como dito, a complexidade e a verbosidade infelizmente são grandes.
Veja como ficará a mesma consulta acima utilizando o Hibernate:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
List persons = criteria.list();
```

Note que o código ficou bem menor e mais simples de ser executado, só que houve a adição do código do próprio Hibernate.

---

### O que escolher?

Algumas perguntas poderiam ser feitas para decidir qual criteria utilizar:

1. Qual o nível da equipe que dará manutenção no projeto?
2. É possível que um pequeno treinamento em criteria seja dado a toda equipe?
3. Meu projeto pode vir a ter consultas muito complexas utilizando criteria?
4. O projeto pode vir a ter problemas de performance?

---

### Existem soluções para usar API nativa?

Existem frameworks no mercado que trabalham com a API nativa do JPA e facilitam o uso da criteria. Um deles é o EasyCriteria (http://easycriteria.uaihebert.com/). As mesmas consultas realizadas acima poderia ser feito como abaixo:

```
EasyCriteria<Person> easyCriteria = EasyCriteriaFactory.createQueryCriteria(entityManager, Person.class);
easyCriteria.getResultList();
```

A vantagem de utilizar esse tipo de framework é que seria possível migrar de Hibernate para OpenJPA, por exemplo.

Outra solução seria o QueryDSL que também tem uma interface para facilitar a consulta e criação de criterias tipadas (não sei se criterias não tipadas funciona). Nesse caso você geraria um meta model e depois utilizar o QueryDSL para gerar as critérias.

Comment: Também vejo o problema mais como uma questão de arquitetura do que de gosto, ambas as soluções são boas, e vejo que a escolha pelo JPA possui mais vantagens do que a escolha pelo hibernate.

Comment: Honestamente até hoje eu sempre utilizei o JPA puro e nunca senti falta do Hibernate, exceto pela criteria. [=

Answer (score 4):

Tentarei responder de forma objetiva, mas também analisando as escolhas de tecnologias em termos gerais.

## Sobre Escolhas de API

Em primeiro lugar, a ideia de *independência de fornecedores* que diversas APIs vendem é tentadora mas, na maioria dos casos, dificilmente ocorre. Veja o caso dos servidores de aplicação, por exemplo. Alguém consegue fazer a distribuição de um mesmo WAR num Tomcat, JBoss, Glassfish ou Weblogic? Cada um contém recursos específicos que variam imensamente de um para outro. Por outro lado, se você ignorar completamente os recursos do seu servidor de aplicação, vai perder as vantagens de usá-lo.

Na prática, você deve escolher dentre as opções disponíveis a que pareça atender melhor os requisitos do seu projeto sem gastar tempo demasiado nisso, pois provavelmente não vale a pena entrar em muitos detalhes se tratando de produtos maduros e comumente usados no mercado. Claro que haverão escolhas erradas e isso é um risco real, então aqui conta muito a vivência e experiência da equipe e do líder.

## Hibernate ou JPA?

Falando agora especificamente de JPA e Hibernate, posso dizer que o JPA realmente teve grandes avanços, mas por vezes você pode precisar de um recurso exclusivo do Hibernate, como [*Dynamic Queries*](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/) ou [*User Types*](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/package-summary.html) (**Update**: o Hibernate 4.3 implementa a especificação JPA 2.1 e possui a anotação `@Converter`, assim não é mais necessário recorrer a um *User Type* para mapear um Enum ou tipo não padrão. De qualquer forma, o importante é a ideia representada no texto.).

Qual escolher então? A resposta é: **nem um nem outro**. Você pode usar as duas APIs ao mesmo tempo. Como sugestão, o JPA poderia ter preferência, mas a API do hibernate seria usada quando necessário. Particularmente eu não tive dificuldades em fazer isso.

## Exemplo #1 de Hibernate + JPA: Queries dinâmicas

Usar uma query dinâmica permite não incluir campos nulos em comandos como `INSERT`, por exemplo, de forma que o valor *default* do banco será usado. No Hibernate isso pode ser feito através do mapeamento XML ou das anotações `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` e `@DynamicInsert` (nas versões mais recentes).

Mas, suponha que você já tenha um persistence.xml e uma entidade JPA como abaixo:

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class MinhaEntidade { ... }
```

E agora? Basta acrescentar a anotação do Hibernate:

```java
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicInsert = true)
public class MinhaEntidade { ... }
```

## Exemplo #2 de Hibernate + JPA: Acesso à Session

E se tiver algum recurso de HQL que iria melhorar muito uma das funcionalidades? Não tem problema, apenas desempacote a `Session`do Hibernate:

```java
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

## Impacto desta abordagem

Obviamente, seguindo esses exemplos, a implementação estaria "amarrada" ao Hibernate.

Porém, o impacto de uma mudança, que eu acredito que sempre haverá, será minimizado a algumas funcionalidades específicas.

Por fim, qual é a chance *real* de você precisar trocar o Hibernate por outra implementação JPA num futuro próximo? Não estou querendo dizer que o Hibernate é absolutamente superior, mas são mínimas as chances de alguém precisar muito de um recurso que só exista, suponhamos, no EclipseLink, e não haja nenhum *workaround* disponível.

Comment: ontem eu li este post e achei bastante interessante, mas quando você se refere a `userType` do `Hibernate`, ontem ao pesquisar no google parece que recentemente lançaram uma `annotation` `@converter` para implementar em uma classe algo semelhante do `Hibernate`. [link](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/mapping-enums-done-right-with-convert.html)

Comment: @Macario1983 O JPA está em constante evolução e muitas das funcionalidades específicas de uma das implementações estão sendo incorporadas (de forma modificada, é claro), no padrão. A versão 2.1 do JPA realmente possui a anotação `@Converter`. Nesse sentido minha afirmação está dessatualizada. Porém, o Hibernate somente lançou a implementação do JPA 2.1 há alguns meses atrás e tem muita gente amarrada com versões antigas. De qualquer forma, agradeço pela informação.